# Reading and writing user settings of an exe from DLL at run time

Tags: c#, settings

I have one DLL inside a installer doing custom action. In custom action I want to set the server name and port of an executable. In this exe i have user settings only, not app.config. Also user settings is in embedded form. I want to modify the user settings of an exe so that when that exe runs read it back and set the parameters in C#. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind, either the installer determines the setting value or the user does.  You can't do it both ways.  An application setting is easy to tinker with in an installer, the app.exe.config file is very easy to find back.  What an installer is expected to do.  A user setting is *not* easy to find back, buried deep inside an AppData directory.  If you want to make a user setting then you'd have an Options menu item.

Comment: I have ServerSetup.exe and ClientSetup.exe. Both share a common customActionDLL and this DLL has Settings.setting file with 2 params ServerName and Port which are setup when user runs the Server setup and at that time i want to load the ClientSetup.exe and find this settings.setting file and set the server name and port. So when clientSetup.exe runs it takes those values from Setting.setting file and make a small settings.xml. My question is how to modufy this Settings.setting (user setting) of ClientSetup.exe. Thanks

Comment: App.config includes a `<userSettings>` section that holds the default values for the user settings. Of course, once the program has run for the first time, these settings are stored elsewhere. But you should be able to modify the `App.config` for the client .exe during installation, before it's run the first time, and achieve your goal. All that said, your question as stated is far too broad. It's not possible to provide a good, useful answer that addresses your concern. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.